# Handle Installation events using c# code?

Tags: c#, installation

How can I install an MSI using C#.NET code? How can I handle installation related events (like install, repair, and uninstall) and execute progress using C#.NET code?

I am new at this.

Could you please give me some guideline for this?

Comment: No, but you can check [wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) and [Windiws Installer on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185688(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"? how do you want to handle it? MSI installation process is handled by Windows installer service, if you want to install your product by not only just double clicking the *.msi file, but also want to do something else before/after the msi process, you can create a wrapper in c# code, do whatever you want and then call windows MSI API to do real install, many products have their own install wizard, but eventually, they call MSI API to do install, unless they do not use MSI, just do a simple file copy during install, but usually, in Windows, MSI is the best choice.